# Excel VBA ODBC connection imported column formatting

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, odbc

I'm looking for a way to reformat some fields that are being imported to my sheet using an ODBC connection. The fields in particular are the date fields. I need to import these as text or some other format because the data in the database will sometimes have dates of "1850-01-01" or "0001-01-01". When importing into excel, the dates just show as #### signs.

Here is the *edited* query I'm currently using:

```vb
Public Sub REFRESH_DATA()

Dim cnDB As New ADODB.Connection    'Declare the connection object.
Dim rsRecords As New ADODB.Recordset 'Declare a Recordset object.

'Open the connection

cnDB.Open "DSN=DB;Database=DB;Servername=server.net;UID=username;Password=password;Port=0000;ReadOnly=0;SQLBitOneZero=0;LegacySQLTables=0;NumericAsChar=0;ShowSystemTables=0;LoginTimeout=0;QueryTimeout=0;DateFormat=1;SecurityLevel=onlySecured;CaCertFile="

rsRecords.Open "SELECT REGION_CD, CUST_NO, EFF_DATE FROM DATABASE.TABLE", cnDB

'Print the records in the correct table
.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsRecords

'Close everything
rsRecords.Close
Set rsRecords = Nothing
cnDB.Close
Set cnDB = Nothing

End Sub
```

The column `EFF_DATE` is the column in question.

Comment: Are you sure the columns are simply not wide enough to show the date? If a column is not wide enough to display a date in full it will only show `#####`

Answer (score 1):

Posting the answer to my own question for future posterity:

Where my `SELECT` statement is `EFF_DATE`, I changed it to read `CAST(EFF_DATE as varchar(30))` which then maintains the format from the database itself.

Comment: That is a *somewhat* acceptable solution, only because *the data* contains dates that are outside the valid date range (format `0` as a short date in Excel, you'll get `1/0/1900`, so the earliest valid date in Excel is `1/1/1900`). The problem it creates, is that Excel won't treat dates as such. See [how to work with dates before 1900 in Excel](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm) for more information.

Comment: In this case, the fact that they aren't formatted as dates within Excel isn't a big deal to me. But I understand where you're coming from if down the road I need to format them as dates.